# Ma'aser for Cohanin

Tags: halacha, maaser-tithes

If fruits were picked by a Cohen for themselves and then someone else eats (with the Cohen's permission, of course), does the person still need to separate Ma'aser?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer:
Firstly, a Cohen gets Teruma, not Ma'aser, technically. (Though in Ezra's time they could [also] be given Maaser.)

Secondly, all fruit grown in Eretz Yisrael is *Tevel* until tithed - i.e. all Terumoth and Maasrot or *taken off* - no matter who grows the fruit.

Therefore, Cohanim may not eat *Tevel*, even if they want to eat fruit from their own trees.

However, a Cohen can keep the Terumah he separates from the fruit he picks or grows. He needn't give it to other Cohanim.

Source: [שלחן ערוך - יורה דעה  סימן שלא - דין נתינתם באיזה מקום](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_54.html)

> **קכג:** כֹּהֵן אוֹ לֵוִי שֶׁמָּכְרוּ פֵּרוֹת תְּלוּשִׁים, קֹדֶם שֶׁתִּגָּמֵר מְלָאכְתָן, וְאֵין צָרִיךְ לוֹמַר אִם מָכַר בִּמְחֻבָּר, הֲרֵי הַתְּרוּמָה וְהַמַּעֲשֵׂר  שֶׁלָּהֶם

Comment: So could he theoretically separate the trumah, "give" it to himself, and then add it back to the original pile?

Comment: Not really, as he has to make the Bracha אשר קדשנו בקדושתו של אהרן וצוונו על אכילת תרומה before eating it.

Comment: He would have to also be Tahor to eat the T'ruma and probably isn't.